# GKE - Unable to deploy Ingress: Getting "default backend - 404" or "502"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I currently have a `Deployment` and a `Service` running fine on GKE. My issue is that I would like to "bind" my external IP:Port to a domain name (on OVH), example:

> http://www.example.com/api/grpc -> 12.345.67.89:8080
>
> http://www.example.com/api/rest -> 12.345.67.89:8081

After a lot of searches, I finally found out that **Ingress** could be my solution. I then updated my yaml in order to combine the three of `Deployment`, `Service`, `Ingress`.

Here is my yaml:

```
# Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License

# Use this file to deploy the container for the grpc-bookstore sample
# and the container for the Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) to
# Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice
  labels:
    app: myservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myservice
          image: gcr.io/<project_id>/myservice:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: myservice
  ports:
    # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: grpc
    # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: rest
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservice-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /grpc
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /rest
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 8081
```

I then try to run a simple request to my REST API using: `http://www.example.com/api/rest/test` with a POST json body containing my name. The API should return `Hello %s` but no, I get either:

- default backend - 404
- 502 Server Error (*The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.*)

I have absolutely no idea about what can be the issue as I followed the Google Documentation

## Edit

I put `http://www.example.com/api/rest` in my example but the followings aren't working neither:

> http://www.example.com/rest
>
> http://12.345.67.89/rest

## Update (March 19th, 2020)

Soo, I could move forward, now my service (which was UNHEALTHY) is HEALTHY, I can connect to it, run CURL on my readinessProbe/livenessProbe endpoint and get 200 OK.

The updated version of my yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: myservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: myservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myservice
          image: gcr.io/<project_id>/myservice:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 8081
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health_check
              port: 8081
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health_check
              port: 8081
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    run: myservice
  ports:
    # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: grpc
    # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: rest
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservice-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: myservice
    servicePort: 8081
```

> kubectl describe pods

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Emixam23:~ emixam23$ kubectl describe pods
Name:               myservice-c57d64669-phrzr
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               gke-cluster-kuberne-default-pool-8b65afeb-qgcm/10.166.0.31
Start Time:         Thu, 19 Mar 2020 11:36:35 -0400
Labels:             pod-template-hash=c57d64669
                    run=myservice
Annotations:        kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container myservice
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.4.2.28
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/myservice-c57d64669
Containers:
  myservice:
    Container ID:   docker://3f9df91ec4e2631d85e0becdb8d1be64bf97fadb5a5b7049c7391eb8cfdf3eee
    Image:          gcr.io/<project_id>/myservice:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/<project_id>/myservice@sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Ports:          8080/TCP, 8081/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 19 Mar 2020 11:36:40 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8081/health_check delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8081/health_check delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-6cppb (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-6cppb:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-6cppb
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From                                                          Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----                                                          -------
  Normal  Scheduled  8m36s  default-scheduler                                             Successfully assigned default/myservice-c57d64669-phrzr to gke-cluster-kuberne-default-pool-8b65afeb-qgcm
  Normal  Pulling    8m35s  kubelet, gke-cluster-kuberne-default-pool-8b65afeb-qgcm  Pulling image "gcr.io/<project_id>/myservice:latest"
  Normal  Pulled     8m32s  kubelet, gke-cluster-kuberne-default-pool-8b65afeb-qgcm  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/<project_id>/myservice:latest"
  Normal  Created    8m31s  kubelet, gke-cluster-kuberne-default-pool-8b65afeb-qgcm  Created container myservice
  Normal  Started    8m31s  kubelet, gke-cluster-kuberne-default-pool-8b65afeb-qgcm  Started container myservice
```

> kubectl describe ingress myservice-ingress

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Emixam23:~ emixam23$ kubectl describe ingress myservice-ingress
Name:             myservice-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Default backend:  myservice:8081 (10.4.2.28:8081)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     myservice:8081 (10.4.2.28:8081)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:                    {"k8s-be-31336--d1838223483f8e56":"HEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:             k8s-fw-default-myservice-ingress--d1838223483f8e0
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:                k8s-tp-default-myservice-ingress--d1838223483f8e0
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s-um-default-myservice-ingress--d1838223483f8e0
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"myservice-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"myservice","servicePort":8081}}}

Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     11m   loadbalancer-controller  default/myservice-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  11m   loadbalancer-controller  ip: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I don't see any error, but I keep getting 404 when I try to hit **XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/health_check**

## Update (March 19th, 2020) - 2

My ingress now look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservice-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /grpc/*
            backend:
              serviceName: myservice
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /rest/*
            backend:
              serviceName: myservice
              servicePort: 8081
```

The `/rest/*` endpoint returns 404, the gRPC haven't been tested yet. About the health, now, I have 3 services and one of them isn't healthy, I don't know why:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Emixam23:~ emixam23$ kubectl describe ingress myservice-ingress
Name:             myservice-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.2.7:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     
        /grpc/*   myservice:8080 (10.4.1.23:8080)
        /rest/*   myservice:8081 (10.4.1.23:8081)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"myservice-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"myservice","servicePort":8080},"path":"/grpc/*"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"myservice","servicePort":8081},"path":"/rest/*"}]}}]}}

  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:         {"k8s-be-30181--d1838223483f8e56":"UNHEALTHY","k8s-be-30368--d1838223483f8e56":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31613--d1838223483f8e56":"HEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:  k8s-fw-default-myservice-ingress--d1838223483f8e0
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:     k8s-tp-default-myservice-ingress--d1838223483f8e0
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:          k8s-um-default-myservice-ingress--d1838223483f8e0
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     14m   loadbalancer-controller  default/myservice-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  13m   loadbalancer-controller  ip: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

In addition: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_6_optional_serve_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer

Comment: I'm seeing `/rest/` path in your `Ingress` resource but you are trying to use `/api/` path which is not specified. Can you try to create a request with `http://your-domain.com/rest`?

Comment: Even without API it doesn’t work.. Even by pointing 12.345.67.98/rest it doesn’t work..

Comment: Please take a look on this official documentation: [Configuring GRPC on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy). It's a guide for exposing GRPC services on GKE with Envoy. Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks, I will once I can, but here I was more looking into REST, why this gRPC link?

Comment: I sent you link to documentation because I saw `GRPC` in your question. Going further, about `Ingress` resource. Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620753/how-to-create-https-endpoint-in-google-cloud-from-http-based-server-for-kubernet/60637536#60637536) with `Ingress` resource and modify your `Ingress` so that it has `- host` parameter as the link provided. You don't need to put `DOMAIN.NAME` there. Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Errors that you provided:

- 404 (Not Found)
- 502 (Bad Gateway)

are related to wrong ingress configuration. When the request does not match the path, it is forwarded to default backend.

Example:

```yaml
      - path: /rest
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 8081
```

This definition will route the traffic to `myservice` only when `/rest` is specified in the request. It will not work with `/api/rest` as well as `/rest/something`.

It could happen that your backends were not working properly because `Ingress` resource did not have enough time to complete the configuration.

To check if `Ingress` resource is configured correctly you can describe it with:

`$ kubectl describe ingress NAME_OF_INGRESS_RESOURCE`

Please take a look below on the part of above command which checks if backend are in `Healthy` or `Unhealthy` state:

```yaml
ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s-be-31720--0838d11870ae50b1":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32475--0838d11870ae50b1":"HEALTHY"}
```

For more information you can visit:
`Google Cloud Platform -> Network services -> Load Balancing`. Find the corresponding forwarding rule and take a look on backend services.

Before you continue make sure that all backends are in `Healthy` state. Please refer to official documentation on [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Ingress healthchecks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#health_checks) and configure them according to your needs.

---

`GKE` Ingress resource by default operates on ports:

- 80 (http)
- 443 (https)

Please take a look on supported protocols by following official documentation: [Cloud.google.com: Load Balance Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#service_annotations_related_to_ingress)

If you are interested in exposing your application on different ports please consider using one of the custom deployed ingress controllers like:

- Nginx-ingress
- Traefik

Please take a look on official documentation [Kubernetes.io: Ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/)

---

Additionally please verify if your pods are are running correctly and run some tests if they are responding with appropriate responses. You can do it by either:

- `kubectl exec -it NAME_OF_THE_POD -- /path/to/shell` and check from the inside of this application pod
- run a ubuntu pod, exec into it and send requests to your application pods.

Please let me know if that helps.

## EDIT

Try this `Ingress` definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: domain-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: DOMAIN.NAME
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 8081
      - path: /admin/* 
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 8081
```

Please change the `DOMAIN.NAME` for one appropriate to your case.

Comment: Hey, this is an interesting answer, I am currently working on it, so I will look at it in details for sure, thanks

Comment: Ok so now, service is healthy. It was actually since a moment, but removing/recreating ingress might have done something, so now it's healthy, but I do get 404 still, so I keep on moving on your answer, thanks for the help

Comment: Everything is running as expecting but ingress IP keeps returning 404... I will update my question

Comment: question update, I tried to give you a better overview of my current solution

Comment: Your `Ingress` resource was created without any `paths` specified. Please adjust your `Ingress` resource in a way that it has `paths`. Here is how to do it: [GKE: Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress). If you are getting HTTP 404 it means that the `Ingress` resource is working and it responds 404 when no path matches the request. Please check if your pod is getting your traffic by `$ kubectl logs NAME_OF_POD`.

Comment: Ok I will look, but in that link, they talk about multiple backend service, me I just have one I want to reach right now. I will keep you update

Comment: This example is for multiple backends but you can specify only one.

Comment: OK, it works, however, I use path/*, but me, I don't want all the requests to fall there, I want only domain.com/api and domain.com/admin, how could I achieve this? default backend will return 404 and only (that's what I want). Thanks for your help, I've never been so far until now!

Comment: Ok let me try! thanks, I don't have the domain yet, but it would come from OVH if so, could it be an issue?

Comment: I don't think this would be an issue if you configure your records inside of OVH platform correctly. You will need to point your domain to the IP of `Ingress` resource. Be aware that above configuration will work only with `Host: ` header matching the `DOMAIN.NAME`.

Comment: I updated my question, I didn't put the host as I don't have any for now.. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209948/discussion-between-dawid-kruk-and-emixam23).