# How to create https endpoint in Google Cloud from http based server for Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, https, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have been trying to create HTTPS endpoint in Google Cloud K8s environment.

I have built a flask application in Python that serves on the waitress production environment via port 5000.

```
serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, ipv6=False, threads=30)
```

I created a docker file and pushed this to the google cloud repository. Then, created a Kubernetes cluster with one workload containing this image. After, I exposed this via external IP by creating LoadBalancer. (After pushing the image to the Google repository, everything is managed through the Google Cloud Console. I do not have any configuration file, it should be through the Google Cloud Console.)

Now, I do have an exposed IP and port number to access my application. Let's say this IP address and the port is: `11.111.11.222:1111`. Now, I can access this IP via Postman and get a result.

My goal is to implement, If it is possible, to expose this IP address via HTTPS as well, by using any google cloud resources. (redirection, creating ingress, etc)

So, in the end I want to reach the application through `http://11.111.11.222:111` and `https://11.111.11.222:111`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I found the answer in Google Cloud Run. It is very simple to deploy HTTP based flask app in the container. As `serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, ipv6=False, threads=30)`(No need for self-certificate or HTTPS in this part, just make sure the HTTP app works) and then push it Cloud Run.

Adjust the service parameters, depend on how much resources do you need to run it. In the machine settings, set the port that you are using in the docker container to be mapped. for instance, in my case, it is `5000`. When you create the service, Google provides you a domain address with HTTPS. You can use that URL and access your resources.

That's it!

**For more information on Cloud Run:**
https://cloud.google.com/serverless-options

**The differences between computing platforms:** https://www.signalfx.com/blog/gcp-serverless-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

A LoadBalancer translates to a network load balancer. You can configure multiple ports for this e.g. 80 and 443. Then your application must handle the TLS part.

The ingress resource creates an HTTP(S) LB

Answer (score 0):

From the GKE perspective you can try to configure `Ingress` resource with `HTTPS` enabled:

**Steps:**

- Create a basic flask app inside a pod (for example purposes only)
- Expose an app via service object of type `nodePort`
- Create a certificate
- Create an Ingress resource
- Test
- Additional information (added by EDIT)

### Create a basic flask app inside a pod (for example purposes only)

Below is a flask script which will respond with `<h1>Hello!</h1>`:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")

def index():
    return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

By default it will respond on port `8080`.

Link to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54381386/12257134) with above script.

### Expose an app via service object of type `nodePort`

Assuming that deployment is configured correctly with working app inside, you can expose it via service object type of `nodePort` with following `YAML` definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: ubuntu
  ports:
  - name: flask-port 
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Please make sure that:

- `selector` is configured correctly
- `targetPort` is pointing to port which is app is running on

#### Create a certificate

For `Ingress` object to work with `HTTPS` you will need to provide a certificate. You can create it with GKE official documentation on: [Cloud.google.com: Managed certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs)

Be aware of a fact that you will need a domain name to do that.

#### Create an Ingress resource

Below is an example `Ingress` resource which will point your requests to your flask application:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: flask-ingress
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: flask-certificate 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: flask-static-ip
spec:
  rules:
  - host: DOMAIN.NAME
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: flask-service
          servicePort: flask-port
```

Please take a specific look on part of `YAML` definition below and change accordingly to your case:

```yaml
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: flask-certificate 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: flask-static-ip
```

Please wait for everything to configure correctly.

**After that you will have access to your application by `domain.name` with ports:**

- `80(http)`
- `443(https)`

> Currently the Ingress only supports a single TLS port, 443, and assumes TLS termination.
>
> --   [Kubernetes.io: Ingress TLS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)

### Test

You can check if above steps are configured correctly by:

- entering https://DOMAIN.NAME in your web browser and check if it responds with `Hello` with HTTPS enabled
- using a tool `curl -v https://DOMAIN.NAME`.

Please let me know if this solution works for you.

### Additional information (added by EDIT)

You can try to configure service object of type `LoadBalancer` which will be operate at layer 4 as @Florian said in his answer.

Please refer to official documentation: [Kubernetes.io: Create external load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)

You can also use [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) controller and either:

- Expose TCP/UDP service by following: [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: Exposing tcp udp services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) which will operating at L4.
- Create an Ingress resource that will have `SSL Passthrough` configured by following: [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: Ssl passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough)

Comment: I do not have a domain name. I created the self-signed certificate just to replicate the certification. I changed my entire app, running on gunicorn with certificate parameters. When I locally execute the docker image (via my machine IP), I have the https connection and I can get the response. But when I push the same image to google., it converts it automatically to HTTP (I use LoadBalancer to expose it). Any idea why?

Comment: You can try to deploy your own `Nginx Ingress` controller by following: [Nginx Ingress installation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/). You would need to change your `Ingress` resource to add `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx` and refer to: [Nginx Ingress: SSL Passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough)

Comment: Going back to issue with `LoadBalancer`. It would require you to post `YAML` definitions of all what is connected to your use case (deployment, loadbalancer).

Comment: @Sojimanatsu I updated my answer. Please take a look at it. I put more options to expose your application.

Comment: Hi, @Dawid Kruk, I found solution by changing the server to gunicorn based instead of waitress and just added self-signed certificate. However, my problem is that the UI does give an error for ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error. Thanks for your help and effort, but I did not use your solution. Google already generates those YAML file and I do not know how to modify them or even should I modify them.